# To read only specific data from file... if string value is passed else to read everything from file c++98

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, search, c++98

I have file named bird.lst. I am trying to read its contents and store the data map data structure.

Where i am looking to read specific bird information,

1. when string value is passed `std::string find = "pigeon";` will get information of `pigeon`. (**working with current code**)
2. if empty value passed to string `std::string find = " ";`, then should able to get all information of birds.(**Not working**)

I am kind off stuck, not able to figure out how to proceed. Suggestions are welcomed thanks in advance.

i have mentioned examples when `std::string find` is passed with empty or bird value with expected output...

bird.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bird.lst");
    std::string find = " ";
    bird_map birds;
    std::string key;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        std::size_t pos = key.find(find);
        attribute_vector attributes;
        std::string value;
        if(pos != std::string::npos && key.substr(pos) == find) {

        while(std::getline(file,value))
        {
            // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
            if (!value.empty() &&
                value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
            {
                value.erase(value.size() - 1);
            }

            // if we found the empty string
            if(value.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            // now split the value into an attribute and a flag
            attribute_pair attribute;
            std::istringstream ss(value);
            ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;
            if(attribute.first != "vaccinated" && attribute.first != "babies" && attribute.first != "sale") {
            // save the value into the vector
               attributes.push_back(attribute);
             }
        }
        // save the bird into the map
        birds[key] = attributes;
    }
}
    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first
                      << "   " << attribute->second
                      << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

bird.lst

```
parrot
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
babies      no
fly         yes
sale        no

pigeon
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         yes
babies      yes
sale        yes

duck
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         no
sale        yes
babies      no

flammingo
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
fly         yes
sale        no
babies      no

eagle
vaccinated  yes
eat         yes
babies      no
fly         yes
```

when `std::string find="duck";` which is working with existing code.

```
duck
   eat   yes
   fly   no
```

when `std::string find=" ";` where it should get data for all birds

```
duck
   eat   yes
   fly   no

eagle
   eat   yes
   fly   yes

flammingo
   eat   yes
   fly   yes

parrot
   eat   yes
   fly   yes

pigeon
   eat   yes
   fly   yes
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that you're "kind off stuck", unfortunately "please help" [is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Can you [edit] your question and rephrase it as a ***specific***, technical C++ question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i have re-phrased question. Also and thanks for letting me know do's and don'ts

Comment: @RemyLebeau your suggestion helped me to resolve the problem. I have posted the answer, can you have a look at it and let me know can we do more better.. Thanks

Comment: Just one thing that struck me: You seem to be learning C++. However, you're learning a dialect that is more than twenty years old. Lots of modern code simply won't work in C++ 98. Also, compilers and IDEs are available without cost, so I'd at least move to C++11 as target.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i will try to upgrade to C++11. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`" "` is not an empty string, `""` is. Nor are you checking for an empty string before searching anyway.

In any case, when `find()` fails to find a match, you are skipping your inner `while` loop altogether, and thus not skipping that current bird's info. So the next outer loop iteration *misinterprets* those unread attributes as if they were bird names, which is wrong.

I suggest writing a function that can read a bird's *complete* info at a time from the file, and then call that function in a loop. On each iteration, if the search string is truly empty, or if it matches the current bird's name, then use that bird's info as needed. And in the latter case, you can then break the loop.

The code you posted as an answer was a good attempt at implementing such a function, but the code still has problems. Aside from it not even fixing the problem of skipping the reading of attributes for non-matching birds, you are splitting the responsibility of reading and processing a bird's details between `main()` and `readBird()` in an awkward way. `main()` is reading each bird's name, then `readBird()` is reading the bird's attributes AND inserting the bird into the `map`. The *sole* responsibility of reading a *complete* bird, name and attributes, should be inside of `readBird()` only, and then `main()` should decide what to do with each *complete* bird that is output, as needed.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string, attribute_vector> bird_map;

bool readLine(std::istream &in, std::string &s)
{
    if (!std::getline(in, s)) return false;
    if ((!s.empty()) && (s.back() == '\r')) s.pop_back();
    return true;
}

bool readBird(std::istream &in, std::string &name, attribute_vector &attributes)
{
    name.clear();
    attributes.clear();

    std::string value;
    attribute_pair attribute;

    do {
        if (!readLine(in, value)) return false;
    }
    while (value.empty());

    name = value;

    while (readLine(in, value) && !value.empty()) {
        std::istringstream iss(value);
        if ((iss >> attribute.first) && ((attribute.first != "vaccinated") && (attribute.first != "babies") && (attribute.first != "sale"))) {
           iss >> attribute.second;
           attributes.push_back(attribute);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bird.lst");
    std::string name, find;
    attribute_vector attributes;
    bird_map birds;

    std::cout << "What would you like to search for? (leave blank for all):" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, find);

    while (readBird(file, name, attributes))
    {
        if (find.empty() || (name.find(find) != std::string::npos))
            birds[name] = attributes;
    }

    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        ++bird)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            ++attribute)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first << "   " << attribute->second << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if want to read more than one bird info for example 2 bird info this wont work.

Comment: i tried to read the arguments from command line where ```argv[1] is file name passed``` then after ```argv[2]``` till the ```argc``` to read till specified bird info's.. it will get data always for ```argv[2]``` argument.

Answer (score -1):

I have added one more function read complete one bird info and calling it in a loop. Then as per requirements passing string empty or with matching bird is passed in find parameter to get specific data.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> attribute_pair;
typedef std::vector<attribute_pair> attribute_vector;
typedef std::map<std::string,attribute_vector> bird_map;

void readBird(std::ifstream &file, std::string &key, std::string &find, bird_map &birds)
{
           attribute_vector attributes;
           std::string value;
           while(std::getline(file,value))
           {
              // in case it has windows encoding with end-of-line = \r\n
              if (!value.empty() &&
                 value[value.size()-1] == '\r')
              {
                  value.erase(value.size() - 1);
              }

              // if we found the empty string
              if(value.empty())
              {
                 break;
              }

            // now split the value into an attribute and a flag
            attribute_pair attribute;
            std::istringstream ss(value);
            ss >> attribute.first >> attribute.second;
            if(attribute.first != "vaccinated" && attribute.first != "babies" && attribute.first != "sale") {
            // save the value into the vector
               attributes.push_back(attribute);
             }
              birds[key] = attributes;
          }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("bird.lst");
    std::string find = "";
    std::string key;

    bird_map birds;
    while(std::getline(file,key))
    {
        if(find.empty())
        {
            readBird(file, key, find, birds);
        }
        else
        {
            std::size_t pos = key.find(find);
            if(pos != std::string::npos && key.substr(pos) == find)
            {
                readBird(file, key, find, birds);
            }
        }
     }
    // now print the data we collected
    for(bird_map::iterator bird = birds.begin();
        bird != birds.end();
        bird++)
    {
        std::cout << bird->first << "\n";
        for(attribute_vector::iterator attribute = bird->second.begin();
            attribute != bird->second.end();
            attribute++)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << attribute->first
                      << "   " << attribute->second
                      << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good attempt at what I suggested earlier, but it still has issues. See the answer I just posted.